# ¿Cómo añadir campos adicionales a la pantalla de registro de Devise?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Actualmente tengo la gema Devise en Rails, quiero añadir mas campos de registro en un tutorial que encontre por internet ya añadi el campo

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :user_role
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Y ejecuto rails db:migration pero no logro ver el campo en la base de datos postgresql

Comment: Si la migración ya la habías ejecutado anteriormente debes de bajarla y luego volverla a subir para que puedas ver los cambios que has realizado a la migración `rails db:migrate:down VERSION=codigo_de_la_migracion` y luego `rails db:migrate:up VERSION=codigo_de_la_migracion`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes añadir mas campos como para cualquier otro modelo (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) usando migraciones por ejemplo.

```
rails generate migration AddNameToUsers
rails generate migration AddLastNameToUsers
...
```

Al ejecutar `rake db:migrate` estos campos serán añadidos a las tablas creadas por devise.

Lo segundo que debes tener en cuenta es que necesitaras modificar las vistas de registro para soportar estos nuevos campos, para ello debes obtener las vistas de devise con `rails generate devise:views` las cuales se crearan bajo la ruta `app/views/devise/`.

En el archivo `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` padres añadir los campos nuevos al formulario.

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.password_field : name%></div>

  <div><%= f.label :last_name %>
      <%= f.password_field : last_name%></div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %>

      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
<%= render "users/shared/links" %>
```

Posteriormente debes añadir un controlador personalizado para soportar la protección a los nuevos campos.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

Y por ultimo redirigir las rutas para las vistas de sign_up hacia tu nuevo controlador. (`routes.rb`)

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

Y listo, con eso deberías de tener tu nuevo formulario de registro.

Answer (score 0):

Crea otra migración donde añades los atributos nuevos a la tabla users, eso es todo

> rails g migration AddUserRoleToUsers user_role